# Show determinate ProgressBar in onProgressUpdate of AsyncTask during the time taken to download data from the internet

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, handler, async-onprogressupdate

I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) to publish progress on the Activity screen in the `onProgressUpdate()` of an AsyncTask, which is used to download some data from the internet. The demo application they have provided is using `Handler` to demonstrate this. I need to use it in an AsyncTask.

Following code snippet is from the code in their demo application.

**My questions are:**

1. onProgressUpdate gets an argument `Progress... values`, and
   according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)), it is "the values indicating
   progress." But **I don't understand what this means, and how to I
   use this argument.** In the examples I have seen, they are doing
   something like:

   ```
   progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
   ```

   **Why are they using only the first value** in the passed array
   (values[**0**])?
2. How does the `AsyncTask` know how long is it going to take to finish
   the download operation. I want to show the ProgressBar progress from
   value 0 to 100 during the time spent to finish the download
   operation.

   By doing `progressBarDeterminate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in
   `onPreExecute` and doing
   `progressBarDeterminate.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in
   `onPostExecute`, we are ensuring that it only shows when the data is
   being downloaded, **but how to we ensure that it progresses from
   starting position to final position *during the time it takes to
   download the data*** (when we don't know precisely how long is it
   going to take to download the data) ?

***CODE FROM DEMO EXAMPLE (It uses Handler, but I need to do this in AsyncTask)***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBarDeterminate progressBarDeterminate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBarDeterminate = (ProgressBarDeterminate) findViewById(R.id.progressDeterminate);

        progressTimer.start();
    }


        Thread progressTimer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(30);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
                    }
                }
            });

            Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                int progress = 0;
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    progressBarDeterminate.setProgress(progress++);
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question, [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...))`()` takes a **varargs** argument. This means that it can take an indefinite number of arguments of the specified type. For example:

```
public void someMethod(String... args) {
    //...
}
```

Could be called either like this, `someMethod("Hi!")`, or this `someMethod("Hi", "there", "welcome", "to", "SO")`.

More on **varargs** can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). These arguments are accessed in the same way as you would an array. If there is only one argument there, then you could use `args[0]`.

**Edit:**
In regards to your second question, as good an example as any is present in the Android Developers [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Namely, the answer really depends on your circumstances. Say in the above example that you need to download ten URLs. A `for` loop is set-up to download each `URL` sequentially, and once that `URL` has finished, `publishProgress()` is called, turning the current value into a percentage figure, `(i / (float) count) * 100)`. Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: As `doInBackground` takes a varargs argument, you can treat `urls` in the same way as you would an array (i.e. `URL[]` object). So, it has a length and `URL` members.

Comment: In my application, in `doInBackground`, the data is coming from a web service and it's type is complex (JSON-like) and then I parse it before returning it from `doInBackground`. So I have no idea how would I find out the number of iterations the for loop should iterate (i.e. the `count` variable). Can you suggest something?

Comment: I had posted the first comment before you edited the question, and after your edit, my question was answered. So I removed the comment.

Comment: @Solace Afraid not, sorry, I've never worked with `JSON` in Android.

Comment: No problem, and thank you so very much for your answer. I am going to accept it. I guess I am going to call `publishProgress` thrice, before making the call to the webservice, after the data has come and before it is parsed, after it is parsed.

Comment: @Solace That would work. Remember as well that if your situation doesn't lend itself well to a percentage-style update bar, you can return anything you like from `publishProgress()`, not just an `Integer`. It could be a `String` for a message, an image resource value etc.